# Order By en Subconsultas de Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, subconsultas, oracle-12c, orderby

Estoy trabajando con una versión 11g de Oracle, intentando realizar una consulta que contiene una subconsulta con ROWNUM y que en el where tiene un ORDER BY obtuve el error:

`Falta el paréntesis derecho`

Ya estuve investigando en internet y veo que no es muy recomendable el uso de los ORDER BY en subconsultas pero en este caso si lo requiero, probé en una versión 12c y agregando `fetch first 1 row only` el error ya no lo obtengo.

En 11g para solventarlo lo tuve que sacar a una consulta externa, probé en un WITH y ahí si me deja realizar el order by, por lo que llegue a la conclusión de que es dependiendo de la posición el que no te deje utilizarlo, algunos casos que tengo identificados son en el WHERE y en el SET del UPDATE, ¿sabrán en que otra posición de realizar subconsultas si permita usar un ORDER BY? para ejemplos anexo mi consulta:

Consulta donde obtuve el error 11g

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS P 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
        USUARIO 
        FROM USERS WHERE (ROWNUM<=10) ORDER BY ID
    ) U ON P.USERNAME=U.USERNAME 
    WHERE 
    P.ID = (SELECT ID FROM PERSONAS WHERE (ROWNUM<=1) ORDER BY ID)
) 
WHERE ROWNUM<=5;
```

Consulta con corrección en 12c

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
    NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS P 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
        USUARIO 
        FROM USERS 
        WHERE (ROWNUM<=10) ORDER BY ID
    ) U ON P.USERNAME=U.USERNAME 
    WHERE P.ID = (
        SELECT 
        ID 
        FROM PERSONAS 
        ORDER BY ID FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
    )
) 
WHERE ROWNUM<=5;
```

Consulta con corrección en 11g

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
    NOMBRE 
    FROM PERSONAS P 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
        USUARIO 
        FROM USERS 
        WHERE (ROWNUM<=10) 
        ORDER BY ID
    ) U ON P.USERNAME=U.USERNAME 
    WHERE P.ID = (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            ID 
            FROM 
            PERSONAS 
            ORDER BY ID
        ) WHERE ROWNUM<=1
    ) 
WHERE ROWNUM<=5;
```

**El error que obtengo es por el WHERE P.ID=** y en el INNER JOIN donde también hay un ORDER BY no me marca ningún error

Espero puedan ayudarme con mi problema, gracias

Comment: yo preguntaria porque necesitas un order y un rownum, cuando se soluciona con un simple max

Comment: Y el error te lo da que ide contra oracle? porque he visto diferentes errores en consultas segun la ide que procesa el query...

Comment: Si estás obteniendo una subconsulta para hacer un join, no ayuda (y sí gasta tiempo) hacer un order by EN la subconsulta. No cambia nada al hacer el join. Lo mismo, si haces un rownum <= 1, si el campo ID es numérico se podría hacer MAX

Comment: A ok entonces podría utilizar en su lugar MAX